# How to identify that String value change or not

Tags: swift, string

How to identify that existing string value changed or not ?

```
var envURLValueChange: String(){
    willSet{}
    didSet{}
}
 if (envURLValueChange.oldValue != envURLValueChange.currentValue){
 // Then do you stuff
}
```

Comment: You already have the seed of your answer in your question. You've created empty willSet and didSet closures. If you need to know after the string value changed, put your logic in the body of the didSet. If you want to know *before* the change takes place, put your code in the body of the willSet. Done.

Comment: @DuncanC I have done willSet didSet failed to put logic inside the closures,  thanks for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use observation

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @objc dynamic var envURLValueChange: String = ""
    
    var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        observation = self.observe(\.envURLValueChange, options: [.old, .new]) { controller, value in
            print(value.oldValue)
            print(value.newValue)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: How its handle in Scene Delegate ?

Comment: do the same thing in Scene Delegate and use willConnectTo instead of viewDidLoad

Comment: Isn’t this what willSet/didSet already does for you? And without having to creat extra properties and use @objc?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson No difference both are the same. I just tried to give a different answere.

Comment: But why suggest something that is more complicated, do you really use this yourself instead of willSet/didSet?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson NO

Answer (score 1):

Unsure as to what you question is asking exactly, but I think I get it. You can do this:

```
var envURLValueChange: String = "" {
   willSet {
       if newValue != envURLValueChange {
          // Do stuff here   
       }
   }
   didSet {
       if oldValue != envURLValueChange {
          // Do stuff here   
       }
   }
}
```

You're best picking one of the `willSet` or `didSet`. if you want to perform code **before** the value changes, then use **willSet** otherwise use **didSet**

Answer (score 1):

No need to extra steps. Please check documentation first. [Property observers](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html)

```
   var yourValue = "" {
        didSet {
            // do stuff here
        }
    }
```